# On validating Address field it is not accepting (') in react native

Tags: regex, react-native, fonts, expo

I have a field in react native,

```
<Field
  component={FormInput}
  maxLength={55}
  name="address"
  validate={[
   formValidators.addressLine,
  ]}
/>
```

In which the validator addressLine uses regex

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9#'\`\. ]*$/
```

Although the back quote "`" is accepted, the single quote in the address field is not accepted.

**Error in the mobile app for single quote**

[image: Single quote not accepted]

**"`"quote is accepted**

[image: other quote accepted]

for references checked the regex in online tool, which is working as expected
[image: Matched Regex values]

I would like to know if I have made any mistake in the regex or is there any other workaround in react-native?
Using versions:

- "react": "16.3.1",
- "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-30.0.0.tar.gz",
- "expo": "^30.0.0",

just for info, using styles for custom fonts as per need.

```
fontFamily: 'proximaNovaRegular' or 'proximaNovaSemibold'
```

Comment: Are you using the pattern in some kind of attribute where `'` is serialized? Try `/^[a-zA-Z0-9&apos;\`.# ]*$/`. Note you do not need to escape backticks in any regex part and dots inside a character class.

Comment: I am sure at my side no serialization is done, but does "Redux-Form" do some data modifications in "field tag" before showing that on the screen? I have no idea about, on searching found no issues of such reported to redux-form...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On testing more found out the redux-form does modify the content in few weird ways. So, used the [normalize method](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/field.md/#-code-normalize-value-previousvalue-allvalues-previousallvalues-gt-nextvalue-code-optional-) that redux-form provide for the field tag.

```
<Field
  component={FormInput}
  maxLength={55}
  name="address"
  normalize={normalizeAddressField}
  validate={[
   formValidators.addressLine,
  ]}
/>
```

where the *normalizeAddressField* is

```
const addressFieldNormalize = value => (value ? value.replace(/’/g, "'") : value);
```

So, I just replaced the quote which is being modified to the one which is recognizable and it helped me out.